# How to loop through each element using recursion in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, foreach

Below is my JSON code which I am also adding through recursion which is a different code. And till here it's giving this JSON format tree. But after that, I am trying to access each element of this tree but getting errors in the children array.

```
const familyTree =   {
            "name": "Shan",
            "gender": "Male",
            "grandfather": "null",
            "grandmother": "null",
            "father": "null",
            "mother": "null",
            "wife": {
                "name": "Anga",
                "husband": "Shan",
                "fil": "null",
                "mil": "null",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Chit",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "grandfather": "null",
                    "grandmother": "null",
                    "father": "Shan",
                    "mother": "Anga",
                    "wife": {}
                }, {
                    "name": "Ish",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "grandfather": "null",
                    "grandmother": "null",
                    "father": "Shan",
                    "mother": "Anga",
                    "wife": {}
                }, {
                    "name": "Vich",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "grandfather": "null",
                    "grandmother": "null",
                    "father": "Shan",
                    "mother": "Anga",
                    "wife": {}
                }, {
                    "name": "Aras",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "grandfather": "null",
                    "grandmother": "null",
                    "father": "Shan",
                    "mother": "Anga",
                    "wife": {}
                }, {
                    "name": "Satya",
                    "gender": "Female",
                    "grandfather": "null",
                    "grandmother": "null",
                    "father": "Shan",
                    "mother": "Anga",
                    "husband": "",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }
    }
```

I am trying this below code but getting an error when it starts looping through children inside wife. Why??????????????

```
 display(familyTree);
var husbandName = 'Chit';
var wifeName = 'Amba';
    const display = async(person) => {
      console.log("person.name = "+ person.name);
      if(person.name == husbandName) {
        var wife = {
          name:wifeName,
          husband:husbandName,
          fil:person.father,
          mil:person.mother,
          children : []
        }
        person.wife = wife;
        console.log("wife = "+JSON.stringify(wife));
      }
      if (person.wife) {
        console.log("person.wife = "+ JSON.stringify(person.wife));
        person.wife.children.forEach(display);
      }
    }
```

This is the console error:

```
(

node:8528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at display (C:\Users\em\Desktop\MindGrep\logic\index.js:103:30)
```

Comment: What is the expected data ? Can you update it in question?

Comment: I would suggest to use map and then Promise all. Also check variable (undefined or null or empty ,[]) before use it

Comment: @AshishSharma Can you write the code please for using promise.all with map?

Answer (score 1):

You recursively call display on objects that as per your root treeFamily object may have a wife property that points to an empty object - ie without a defined children property.

From your familyTree object children, either remove completely the wife property that point to an empty object, or add a children property pointing to an empty array to them.

Comment: I think I can also avoid this by doing breadthwise recursion. I was applying depth-wise recursion. Can you tell me how to do breadth wise recursion?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I ran you code but is run fine except function declaration.

```
const familyTree = {
  name: "Shan",
  gender: "Male",
  grandfather: "null",
  grandmother: "null",
  father: "null",
  mother: "null",
  wife: {
    name: "Anga",
    husband: "Shan",
    fil: "null",
    mil: "null",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Chit",
        gender: "Male",
        grandfather: "null",
        grandmother: "null",
        father: "Shan",
        mother: "Anga",
        wife: {}
      },
      {
        name: "Ish",
        gender: "Male",
        grandfather: "null",
        grandmother: "null",
        father: "Shan",
        mother: "Anga",
        wife: {}
      },
      {
        name: "Vich",
        gender: "Male",
        grandfather: "null",
        grandmother: "null",
        father: "Shan",
        mother: "Anga",
        wife: {}
      },
      {
        name: "Aras",
        gender: "Male",
        grandfather: "null",
        grandmother: "null",
        father: "Shan",
        mother: "Anga",
        wife: {}
      },
      {
        name: "Satya",
        gender: "Female",
        grandfather: "null",
        grandmother: "null",
        father: "Shan",
        mother: "Anga",
        husband: "",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
};

var husbandName = "Chit";
var wifeName = "Amba";
const display = async(person) => {
  console.log("person.name = " + person.name);
  if (person.name == husbandName) {
    var wife = {
      name: wifeName,
      husband: husbandName,
      fil: person.father,
      mil: person.mother,
      children: []
    };
    person.wife = wife;
    console.log("wife = " + JSON.stringify(wife));
  }
  if (person.wife) {
    console.log("person.wife = " + JSON.stringify(person.wife));
    person.wife.children.forEach(display);
  }
};

display(familyTree);
```